# Why Am I Getting a SystemStackError?

Tags: ruby

```
module CallableDict
  def method_missing method
    puts x["#{method}"]
  end
end
```

The above code is my module, it makes hash keys callable. When I run it though...

```
require 'callabledict'
x = {"foo" => "ruby"}
x.extend CallableDict
x.foo
```

I get the following...

```
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
    from /Users/Solomon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/workspace.rb:80
Maybe IRB bug!
```

Why? Hpw can I fix this?

Comment: I guess you call `x` in `method_missing` which is a recursive call, since that also calls x again and again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually `x` is a `self` so you can rewrite it like this:

```
module CallableDict
  def method_missing method
    puts self["#{method}"]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In the implementation of `method_missing`, `x` is treated as a method name, as Ruby has not seen `x` as a variable in the right scope. When the interpreter sees `x["#{method}"]`, it thinks that you are indexing into a hash or other object returned from a method called `x`. Because there is no method called `x`, Ruby calls your `method_missing`, which once again calls itself, repeating this process until Ruby runs into a stack overflow.

The fix is simple. As @nash stated above, you must replace `x` with `self`, because in `method_missing`, the *name* `x` has no significance, but the *name* `self` is the same reference (in C terms, they are the same pointer). Also, you could make the code more readable by doing this in the implementation of `method_missing`:

```
puts self[method.to_s]
```